# ASP.NET MVC 3 Ajax.BeginForm() cannot find the Controller Action when in Views/Shared Folder?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Anyone know what's the deal here?  If I put an Ajax.BeginForm into a cshtml file in the

### Views/Shared folder

it does not work:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestAction", "Test", new AjaxOptions
 {
     HttpMethod = "Post"
 }
 , new { id = "submitTestForm" })) {}
```

but a regular Html.BeginForm does:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestAction","Test",FormMethod.Post,new {id="submitTestForm"})) {}
```

But if I move it up under the

### Views/Test folder (the controller in this case would be TestController)

It works fine.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You have to many closing brackets maybe ?

Comment: No, if I move it up it's good. Possible copy/paste issue here

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, did you try setting a breakpoint in the TestAction and see if it's been hit?

Comment: @user1736525 when I say it doesn't work, I mean it won't even compile (if you compile views that is).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it is not working form shared folder, but you can get rid of the ajax form and use normal form and write some handwritten CLEAN javascript yourself to do the same

```
@using(Html.Beginform("testAction","test",FormMethod.Post, new { id="submitTestFrm"})
{

  <input type="submit" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     $("#submitTestFrm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var _this=$(this);
        $.post(_this.attr("action"),_this.serialize(),function(response){
          //do something with the response.
      });
     });    
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Agreed. This is what we normally do. However we had a need to use the Ajax crap instead. That is why I'm just now coming across this issue.

Comment: Code looks pretty good. In a code review I'd hit you up for using closest("form") ;)

Comment: @ferventcoder did you find a solution for this. am facing same issue - the Ajax.Beginform not finding controller or ActionResult under shared folder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (**but in ASP.Net MVC 5**) when I realized I was actually using the wrong overload of the BeginForm-method. Simply changing to this resolved the issue for me:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestAction","Test", null, FormMethod.Post, new {id="submitTestForm"})) {}
```

Notice the **null** parameter being sent for the routevalues object.

Comment: Was this with ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: It was not, perhaps I should clarify that in my answer. It was ASP.Net MVC 5.